# tar skip trying to compress files by extension

Tags: tar, file-format, compression, gzip

I noticed when compressing a directory with tar+gzip that the compressor was spending a lot of time trying to compress mp4 video files in vain. This makes me wonder: does gzip or any other common compression format (ex. zip, 7z, xz) support skipping compressing files (*but still including them uncompressed* in the archive) by extension?

Comment: Did you try tar's -a (autocompress) to determine compression based on suffix?

Comment: @ubfan1 that just chooses the compression tool - it doesn't distinguish the files being compressed?

Comment: Were it possible, it would be explained in `man tar`. Have you checked there?

Comment: I suspect it's not possible in tar, but maybe in other compression formats